# Looping through variables to check if defined

Tags: perl

I am attempting to check a bunch of variables to ensure that they are defined.  I thought I would put the variable names in an array and loop over the array checking if each variable was defined.  However, as best I can understand it, the use of symbolic references for lexical variables (defined by "my") does not work.

Is there a way in Perl to check if a large number of lexical variables are defined without resorting to putting each variable name into a defined statement manually?  It would seem to be better if I could create an array or something to hold the names of the variables whose defined status I wish to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also put a ref to the var in the array.

```
my @vars = (
   [ '$x', \$x ],
   [ '$y', \$y ],
   [ '$z', \$z ],
);

for (@vars) {
   my ($name, $ref) = @$_;
   print("$name is undefined\n") if !defined($$ref);
}
```

I don't see what's so hard about including a name when you include the variable. The alternative is to have PadWalker scan the internals. I wouldn't use that in production, but it can be useful in a debugging tool.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I couldn't quite figure out how to do!  And it looks like if I want to do the same thing for arrays I do something very similar:

    my @vars = (  
       [ '@x', \@x ],  
       [ '@y', \@y ],  
       [ '@z', \@z ],  
    );  

    for (@vars) {  
       my ($name, $ref) = @$_;  
       print("$name is undefined\n") if (not @$ref);  
    }

Comment: `print("$name is empty\n")`, but yeah.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to rethink the structure of your code. Having a large number of lexical variables like that suggests a bad design - should they perhaps not live in a hash or an array? Then they could be iterated over much simpler.